# Maven swizzle dependency doesn't work

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I try to compile this [pom](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/swizzle/swizzle-confluence/1.6.2/swizzle-confluence-1.6.2.pom) file but it doesn't download

```
import org.codehaus.swizzle.confluence.*;
```

dependency. I get pom file from maven's site. [Search Maven Swizzle](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cswizzle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the POM **of** the `swizzle-confluence` library, i.e. the POM file that the **library's project** uses for its **own** build.

Instead, you need to add the dependency declaration **for** this library to **your project's** POM. In Maven Central search, this is available on the left-hand-side of the version information page, under ***Dependency Information***.

So, open up the page for [`swizzle-conflunce:1.6.2`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.codehaus.swizzle%7Cswizzle-confluence%7C1.6.2%7Cjar), and you can see that this is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.swizzle</groupId>
    <artifactId>swizzle-confluence</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, to help yourself in the future, consider reading [about the POM](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html) and [how dependencies work](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Comment: @user1472060 : you're welcome. BTW, on StackOverflow it is good practice to [accept the answer that helped you solve the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). That way the question won't be marked as unanswered.